# NULL check for integers in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function in an pure virtual class that is inheritted by multiple classes. This function looks something like:

```
virtual quint32 myClass::getIntValue() = 0
```

In some classes that inherrit this function a default value should be returned since they cannot implement this function (yet). However any quint32 that I pick can also be a valid return value. So for example if I pick "0" to be the default value, I can check the return value to be "0" and act accordingly (for example ignoring that value). However there will be cases when "0" will be a valid return value that makes sense.

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: @sbabbi So every call to `getIntValue()` needs to be wrapped in a `try-catch` block?  Do you know how expensive a stack unwinding is!?  I like exceptions, but they should be used in _exceptional_ circumstances - just calling a method is not one of them.

Comment: If you can use `qint32` instead of a `quint32`, you can have -1 as default invalid value, and still something like 2 billion of possible valid values.
Or if you want to use `quint32`, you can consider -1 (`0xFFFFFFFF`) to be the default value. Or you need every possible `quint32` as valid?

Comment: `since they cannot implement this function (yet).` That means that eventually all the functions will return a value. When this happens you will be stuck with an `optional` everywhere that is guaranteed to be always non-empty.  Stack unwinding is super-expensive, but I'd rather heavily penalize the functions that do not behave properly than penalize the "good" ones just a bit.

Comment: The answer about using `boost::optional` is spot-on. That's what you need to use, since that's your exact use case.

Comment: @cmannett85 If wrong use of `getIntValue` is a programming error, then `try-catch` blocks are unnecessary and a mistake. The exception must not be caught, and the program should abort. There should be some other way for the caller to determine whether it's safe to call `getIntValue` in such a case. Or use an optional type, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Use [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).  Hopefully it'll be added to the C++17 standard.

Answer (score 2):

You could return a QPair or pass a bool& like:

> virtual quint32 myClass::getIntValue(bool &valid) = 0;

or

> virtual QPair< quint32,bool > myClass::getIntValue() = 0;

Answer (score 1):

If you can use an optional type, use it.

Otherwise, since the caller of `getIntValue` has to do the checks anyway, it'd be useful to force it to do the checks. Have a method the caller can use to check if `getIntValue` is implemented. A quick inspection of such an API makes it obvious that you need to call `hasGetIntValue` before you use it. It self-documents not much worse than had you used an optional type.

```
class MyClass {
  ...
  virtual quint32 getIntValue() const { Q_ASSERT(false); } // or abort()
  virtual bool hasGetIntValue() const { return false; }
};

class Class : public MyClass {
  ...
  quint32 getIntValue() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE { return 42; }
  bool hasGetIntValue() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE { return true; } 
}
```

The caller can then check and avoid the call altogether:

```
if (myClassInstance.hasGetIntValue()) {
  auto value = getIntValue();
  ...
} else {
  // can't call getIntValue(), do something else
}
```

This approach will catch callers that don't do the check at runtime.

Note that getters usually can be declared `const`, and reimplementations should be declared with `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` to ensure that you're actually implementing existing virtual methods, not adding new ones.

An alternative approach would be to implement some lightweight optional value class if you can't use `boost::optional` for whatever reason.